# Meta og tag image is not updating when the url is shared on Linkedin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, css

I'm facing a problem in my WordPress site, I have a url for which I'm trying to change the image which appears when the url is shared on social platforms. The image is getting updated for all the social platform except Linkedin.

I have tried updating the image with meta:og tag but Linkedin still shows the older image. Linkedin takes around 7 days for the cache to get cleared, but I have waited now for 1 month, still no update in Image.

Wordpress offers a way by which custom images can be passed by AddToAny wordpress plugin, below is the code for that:

```
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($EM_Event->post_id));

// Pass custom image to AddtoAny plugin

if (function_exists('ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT')) {
    ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(array(
        'linkmedia' => $img_src[0],
        'linkname'  => $EM_Event->event_name,
        'linkurl'   => get_the_permalink($EM_Event->post_id),
    ));
}
```

Even after passing the image via above code, I'm facing the same issue.

Any help shared would be great! Thanks

Comment: `'linkurl'   => get_the_permalink($EM_Event->post_id),` remove the coma at the end ?

Comment: @Cid the problem is not with the syntax, I need a way by which the image would get update when it it shared on Linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the cache time: ***"...LinkedIn caches link preview content for 7 days."*** (Source: [LinkedIn: How to Clear LinkedIn Link Preview Cache](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-clear-linkedin-link-preview-cache-ananda-kannan-p/).)

To refresh the cache, simply check your URL at the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com): This tool not only refreshes the cache, but it inspects the page code, shows possible values that were considered for `title` or `summary`, shows which was taken, and then explains why it made those decisions.  Very useful for situations like this!

If you're still not certain, you can test by testing out the preview for `example.com?test=1` instead of for `example.com`.  Since the URL is technically different, but it's not a value being used by the page, it should miss the LinkedIn preview cache and generate a new preview.